# SQL Server: Multiply a result row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, text, output

I have several result rows from a `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT a.code, CONCAT('text output', a.result)
FROM table1 a
```

Result looks like

```
code |  text
a    | 'text output a'
b    | 'text output b'
```

One column contains concatenated text output. I simply want to have each result row duplicated with slightly different text outputs (which can be hardcoded).

The expected result should be like

```
code |  text
a    | 'example 1: text output a'
a    | 'example 2: text output a'
b    | 'example 1: text output b'
b    | 'example 2: text output b'
```

In essence, I want - for each result - to put *example 1* and *example 2* in front. How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way in your case is following:

```
SELECT a.code, CONCAT('example 1: text output', a.result)
FROM table1 a
union all
SELECT a.code, CONCAT('example 2: text output', a.result)
FROM table1 a
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with recursive query

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(
    code CHAR(1)
    , txt VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES 
('a', 'text output a')
,('b', 'text output b')
,('c', 'text output c')

;WITH q1 AS(
    SELECT 1 ex, tbl1.code, tbl1.txt
    FROM @table tbl1
        UNION ALL
            SELECT ex+1, q1.code, q1.txt 
            FROM q1
            WHERE q1.ex < 3
)
SELECT q1.code, concat('Example ', q1.ex, ': ', q1.txt) [text]
FROM q1
ORDER BY q1.code, q1.ex
```

you can change number 3 according how many times you want each row to be displayed